# How to Convert an Html to a PDF file and save it Using iTextSharp in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    #region convert HTML To PDF
    static public void HTMLToPdf(string Contents, string FilePath, string strValue)
    {

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

        //PDF for compliance overdue report.
        if (strValue == "due")
        {

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(FilePath,FileMode.Create));
        }
        //PDF for other compliance reports.
        else
        {

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create));
        }
        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);

        hw.Parse(new StringReader(Contents));

        document.Close();
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Please clarify the question. What is your problem, error logs, efforts so far...

Comment: No error is shown.I have already appended an html page in the above code.Now i have to convert it into a pdf file and save that file into the drive automatically when the exe is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do this,But you can try this:

[HTML to PDF Online API](http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/)

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/158761)

Comment: I am confused that from where we can call the html file ?